# Cannot unmount CIFS mount?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, cifs

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS.  I have a NAS using CIFS protocol.  I have mounted a share. I am not using fstab at all. Running mount yields the following:

```
//10.0.1.38/FOO on /home/s3backup/S3Backup/mnt/FOO type cifs (ro,mand)
```

When I attempt to unmount it I get the following:

```
$ sudo umount mnt/FOO           
This utility only unmounts cifs filesystems.
This utility only unmounts cifs filesystems.
```

I also tried the -l option and it yielded the same results.  Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: How about `sudo umount /home/s3backup/S3Backup/mnt/FOO`?

Comment: Huh, there's a bug report that sounds vaguely like that: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cifs-utils/+bug/648609 but the report seems to go nowhere.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem on CentOS 5.4 and found a workaround in a [RedHat bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=219512), which recommended using `-i` which tells it to not use the `umount.<filesystem>` helper.

In your case, just run

```
umount -i /home/s3backup/S3Backup/mnt/FOO
```

This worked, although it will write the following to stderr:

```
umount: //10.0.1.38/FOO: not found
umount: /home/s3backup/S3Backup/mnt/FOO: not mounted
umount: //10.0.1.38/FOO: not found
umount: /home/s3backup/S3Backup/mnt/FOO: not mounted
```